# Constraint a neural network loss function with Keras/Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, loss-function

I want to create a neural network that has a multivariate outcome to predict a univariate target. The loss function is the sum of the mse for each of the network's outcome pointing to the target. I want to impose an orthogonal constraint, i.e. each network outcome must be orthogonal to the error between al the other network outcomes and the target variable. I have built a custom loss function (example with two network's outcome:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    # Mean squared error for each outcome
    mse1 = tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred[0])
    mse2 = tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred[1])

    ortho_loss = K.mean( (y_pred[1] - K.mean(y_pred[1])) * ((y_pred[0] - y_true) - K.mean(y_pred[0] - y_true)) )

    # Total loss
    total_loss = mse1 + mse2 +  K.mean(1*tf.keras.activations.relu(ortho_loss - 0)) + K.mean(1*tf.keras.activations.relu(-ortho_loss + 0))

    return total_loss
```

but it does not provide satisfactory results. Any ideas if this is feasible?

Comment: you need to be clear at "satisfactory results", what would that be?

Comment: It does not seem that the optimization is meeting the constraint. For instance if I only use one of the constraint, the sign of the correlation is either positive or negative, completely at random. So my main question is: am using the Keras function in the right way?
The other question is whether imposing such a strict constraint might be feasible in the neural network context.